# Issue with TextField with multiple styles when typing. Only last char is styled

Tags: android, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

I want to apply bold style to the text I am typing, after selecting a button on my UI
I don't understand why only the last character is bolded and all the previous one are set to the default style.
What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the TextField remembering what was previously bolded?

Example:

What I want:
Here is exampleof**the textI want**

What I get:
Here is exampleofthe textI wan**t**

```
 val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }


TextField(
    value = textState.value,
    onValueChange = {

        val prevPos = textState.value.selection.start
     

        if (selectedButton1.value) {
            val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
                append(it.text)

                addStyle(
                    SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
                    prevPos,
                    it.text.length
                )
            }

            textState.value =  it.copy(annotatedString, it.selection, it.composition)
        } else {
            textState.value =  it
        }
    },

    placeholder = { Text(placeholder, style = textStyle) },
    modifier = modifier,
    enabled = enabled,
    textStyle = textStyle,...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous pos is calculated each time; thus it is just the last character. The new TextFileValue will have the old one +1 because the cursor moved.
if you want the selection from a button press you can use another state.

```kotlin
var prevPos by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
```

In button:

```
onClick = {
   // Before typing:
   prevPos = textState.value.selection.start
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me where to initialize this prevPos? I did add it above the TextField, but now the entire text I am typing gets bolded. Even the previous one which should not be bolded.

Comment: also what if I want to have bold text in multiple parts of the text?

Comment: see edit for first, for the multiple parts you need to save the start and end positions in the text that should be bold. And pass it to multiple addStyle

Comment: could you give me a small example of how to also save the end position and in the same time apply the bold style? Please? Thx

Comment: Options: a) Another class with start and end index; or b) encode it in the text string like '<b>' at start of bold and '</b>' at end. This information can be parsed inside the annotation builder.